# ios facebook sdk get and display username

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been working with the facebook sdk and parse and I am trying to retrieve a users facebook name but the documentation doesn't give me sufficient help and most tutorials on the net are out dated.

Can anyone tell how I can get a users name from the facebook sdk to display as a text label ? This would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: In facebook SDK there are sample codes check.  https://github.com/facebookarchive/ios-howtos

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement following **FBLoginViewDelegate**

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{
 NSLog(@"user is %@ %@", [user objectForKey:@"email"], user.name);
}
```

Comment: Hi, i cannot seem to implement the FBLoginViewDelegate, I can only implement the FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate ? and when I try use your code I get errors? Is the code from an out dated sdk you gave me ? Here is my screen shot of errors. http://postimg.org/image/kb38j709j/ Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve it in this way:

```
 FBRequest *request = [[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:FBSession.activeSession graphPath:@"me"];

[request startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                       NSDictionary < FBGraphUser > *my,
                                       NSError *error)
 { 
    NSString *username = my[@"username"];
 }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help but how come I get all these errors ? I think its because the code you gave me is for an outdated sdk ? His is a screen shot of my errors http://postimg.org/image/qwlsq8uyb/

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out, you have to request the current users profile information than set your label with a "key" which in this case is called "name"

```
 FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me"
                                                                   parameters:nil];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);

        _usernameText.text = result[@"name"];

    }];
```